# Decision Tree Performance, ML

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

If we don't give any constraints such as `max_depth`, `minimum number of samples for nodes`, Can decision tree always give 0 training error? or it depends on Dataset? What about shown dataset?

edit- it is possible to have a split which results in lower accuracy than parent node, right? According to theory of decision tree it should stop splitting there even if the end results after several splitting can be good! Am I correct?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decision tree will always find a split that imrpoves accuracy/score

For example, I've built a decision tree on data similiar to yours:

[image: Accuracy by depth]

A decision tree can get to 100% accuracy on any data set where there are no 2 samples with the same feature values but different labels.

This is one reason why decision trees tend to overfit, especially on many features or on categorical data with many options.

Indeed, sometimes, we prevent a split in a node if the improvement created by the split is not high enough. This is problematic as some relationships, like `y=x_1 xor x_2` cannot be expressed by trees with this limitation.

So commonly, a tree doesn't stop because he cannot improve the model on training data.
The reason you don't see trees with 100% accuracy is because we use techniques to reduce overfitting, such as:

1. Tree pruning [like this relatively new example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#minimal-cost-complexity-pruning). This basically means that you build your entire tree, but then you go back and prune nodes that did not contribute enough to the model's performance.
2. Using a [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio) instead of gain for the splits. Basically this is a way to express the fact that we expect less improvement from a 50%-50% split than a 10%-90% split.
3. Setting hyperparameters, such as `max_depth` and `min_samples_leaf`, to prevent the tree from splitting too much.

Comment: Thanks, very nicely explained.  I wanted to add a figure in this comment but can't. So can you please have a look into this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61364693/splitting-in-decision-tree?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly where a split will be, because both gini impurity and entropy are harder for us to simply imagine. I would say that in that case, as well as in the case above, the first split would be something like `x<=T` where `T` is a threshold that takes almost only 1 label to the left of it. For example on data similiar to the one above I'm getting `x<=-0.04`. This gives us one node that you are almost 100% correct on (hence it's very pure), and 1 smaller node you are worse on.
In the example you provided, I'm guessing somewhere between 0.7-0.8 would be optimal

Comment: In the input shown in the question(splitting in decision tree) it will split one white(+1) data point and rest as its children, right? but then we will end up predicting that white(+1) data point to be negative, right? then we can't get 100% training accuracy!!   
Can you please answer this question there itself
   stackoverflow.com/questions/61364693/splitting-in-decision-tree

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61364693/splitting-in-decision-tree